# Configuring and debugging example project of an Android Cast TV Receiver

Tags: android, android-studio, casting, chromecast, android-tv

I downloaded a sample project on github ,https://github.com/googlecast/CastAndroidTvReceiver/tree/master/app-java
Reading the README and following the guidelines, it is not enough to compile and run the package on the Android Studio IDE and install it on my android box, but you have to do a series of configurations .
From what I understand you have to associate through this link https://cast.google.com/u/0/publish/?hl=it&hl=it&hl=it#/overview (after registration to the console) the serial of the chromecast device that resides in my case in the Android TV box and a web receiver application that I published with firebase https://labcast-9f052.web.app/ following the guide android https://developers.google.com/cast/codelabs/cast-receiver?hl=it#0 .
Then in the manifest of the example app I have uncommented a TAG <intent-filter> already written from line 45 and set the url parameter '<data android:host=' of the web receiver previously published (I suppose you have to do so).

I still have not quite clear the configuration to do, but reading the various tutorials I understood so and I could still be wrong, however my request is if it was possible for the sample application taken from Github to intercept any transmission by another device on my androidtv box and in that case what would and would be enough to configure. Thank you very much. Greetings